# What is standard practice for truncating text for narrow screen widths?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

A simple example: Let's say in the footer of my website at 1024px, along with other links, I have a "Terms & Conditions" link. Using media queries, at `max-width: 320px` I would want to shorten the link to simply read "Terms". I could approach this two ways:

***JQUERY APPROACH***

HTML

```
<p class='terms'>Terms &amp; Conditions</p>
```

JQUERY

```
// Use match media or something similar to determine breakpoint then use this function:
$('.terms').text('Terms');
```

***CSS APPROACH***

HTML

```
<p class='terms'>Terms <span>&amp; Conditions</span></p>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .terms span {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

Is there a standard practice for this? It would seem to me that the CSS method would be most efficient.

Comment: I would definitly go for the CSS solution.

Comment: I think the CSS solution is better. I don't know about standard practices, but if you want it to wrap to two lines or get broken into syllables, you can give hints on where a word should break between syllables with `&shy`. You could also hide the rest of the text with an ellips or have overflow hidden on the horizontal.

Comment: "Terms…" probably seems a little strange though @juuga.

Comment: Haha, good point @BoltClock. I saw it as "Terms & Cond..." in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not use jQuery anywhere else on this website, you should go with the CSS solution. If you do already use jQuery, however, both approaches are equally effective - users will not notice any difference.

Comment: Which would be better for performance? Or is this case too negligible for any noticeable gains?

Comment: The difference would be negligible even if you have hundreds of such texts on your web page.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit of preference but I think the CSS solution is better from a maintenance perspective. I would expect to find the definition for presentation in CSS (the direction that most responsive design frameworks have been going)